# How to open pin planner in Xilinx Vivado?

Tags: vhdl, vivado, quartus

I am an Intel Quartus user getting to know Xilinx Vivado. I am using Xilinx Vivado for the first time. I am using Digilent ARTY S-7 FPGA board for learning purpose.

I am have created a blinking LED program that I am able to synthesize. I can also see that the creators of the FPGA board have given me something called constraints file which is an XDC file. I cannot for the life of me find where the I/O planner GUI is supposed to be for the current active project.

I have the following questions:

1. How do I open the Xilinx Vivado equivalent of Intel Quartus pin planner GUI? This is used to assign specific FPGA pins to specific ports of the user design and also specify the I/O standard.
2. Does Xilinx Vivado put all constrains into a single XDC file rather than have separate files for timing constrains, I/O pin constraints, floor plan constraints, IP specific constrains e.t.c.?

Comment: Does this https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_2/ug935-vivado-io-clock-planning-tutorial.pdf help with item 1?

Comment: Yes the problem is solved by this "Lab 2: Post-Synthesis I/O Planning" which is not present in any youtube tutorial I have seen so far.